# Mongo DB write operation in shard setting

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongoDB while going through some tutorial I got a question in my mind that, in sharded environment during reading operation "mongos" first checks config server to get details to which shard it has to query.  But what about during write operation does it first checks to which shard it has to perform write operation?

Thanks in advance,
Kitty

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer based on the current stable release of [MongoDB v3.2](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production).

The [config servers](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/) store the cluster's metadata in the config database. The [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongos/#bin.mongos) instances **cache** this data and use it to route reads *and* writes to shards.

MongoDB only writes data to the config servers when the metadata changes, such as:

- After a [chunk migration](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-migration/), or
- After a [chunk split](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-splitting/).

MongoDB reads data from the config server in the following cases:

- A new mongos starts for the first time, or an existing mongos restarts.
- After change in the cluster metadata, such as after a chunk migration.

See also: [Sharded Cluster Mechanics](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-mechanics/).